# SQL - IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO distance (deviceID,datum,tavolsag)
 SELECT 
deviceID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) as datum, 
sum(case when distanceKM/1000<416 then distanceKM/1000 else 0 end) as tavolsag
FROM eventdata 
GROUP BY datum,deviceID;
```

I would like to know how can avoid data duplication when I run the query on daily basis/ or use the "if exists update else insert" method.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UNIQUE constraint on (deviceID, datum), then you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`

```
INSERT INTO distance (deviceID, datum, tavolsag)
SELECT d.deviceID
     , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(d.timestamp)) as datum
     , SUM(CASE WHEN d.distanceKM/1000<416 
                THEN d.distanceKM/1000
                ELSE 0 END
       ) AS tavolsag 
  FROM eventdata d
 GROUP BY datum, deviceID
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE tavolsag = VALUES(tavolsag)
```

When this statement is executed, this will attempt the insert, and if the inserting would violate a unique key constraint, rather than throw an error, MySQL will execute an UPDATE instead, equivalent to:

```
UPDATE distance
   SET tavolsag  = ?
 WHERE device_id = ?
   AND datum     = ?
```

---

If there are multiple unique constraints, then the action depends on which unique constraint is flagged as being violated. The actual update that is performed will be relative to the unique constraint that would have thrown the error.

Comment: thanks for explaining! the deviceId and datum is a unique constraint.

Comment: @Peter: one other note: if your target table has an AUTO_INCREMENT column defined, then running the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement will burn through auto_increment values even when the statement performs the UPDATE action. MySQL attempts the INSERT first (and that's when it uses the AUTO_INCREMENT value), and then falls back to an UPDATE only on a duplicate key exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 INSERT INTO distance (deviceID,datum,tavolsag)
 SELECT deviceID,datum,tavolsag from(select 
deviceID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) as datum, 
sum(case when distanceKM/1000<416 then distanceKM/1000 else 0 end) as tavolsag
FROM eventdata 
GROUP BY datum,deviceID)t
on duplicate key update set datum=......, tavolsag = .....
```